# Changing an element in a dictionary value array in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Say I have a `Dictionary<int, string[]> dict`. How could I change a specific element in a string[] in that dictionary, while keeping the others the same?
I tried something like this

```
dict[0].ElementAt(0) = "Something Different";
```

but the left hand side isn't a variable/property/indexer.

Comment: I may be wrong but a simple `dict[0][0] = "new value";` could work

Comment: Only use `ElementAt` when you don't have an indexer that you can use instead.  Also it only returns the item at that position it will not allow you to replace the item at that position.

Answer (score 2):

[`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method that returns something, it is not the setter. You can use the array-indexer.

```
dict[0][0] = "Something Different";
```

Answer (score 1):

`ElementAt` is just an accessor it does not support assignment, you should try a direct index access like:

```
dict[0][0] = "Your String";
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed.